# と in 急だとは思わなかった

Tags: grammar, particle-と

It's translated as "I didn't think it was so steep".
It looks to me that と here is used a a nominalizer, but I didn't find any dictionary to confirm this.
Also, can it be replaced by other nominalizer, like の, 事 or 物?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The と here is sometimes called a "quotative" particle, as if it marks the end of a statement, which the rest of the sentence describes: 「急だ」​**と**[は]思わなかった。  The は here is used a bit like emphasis, and isn't strictly necessary from a grammatical perspective.

Another way of looking at it is like the "that" coordinating conjunction in English: *"I didn't think **that** it was so steep."*  While this coordinating "that" is often omissible in English, this と is not omissible in Japanese.